# Tuleap Database Copy Issue

Tags: php, tuleap

Currently im using 6.6 Tuleap version in my live server, now i decided to upgrade over it,before doing that so i want to check some functionality in the latest version. So i installed the latest version of Tuleap in my test server machine,now what i need to know is, what are the database files i need to copy from my live server to the test server.I have copied the codendi alone,and it works fine, but in the subversion part i couldnt able to copy the files and its not even allowing the admin to checkout the files.

Share the list of db files what i need to copy.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion files are in /var/lib/codendi, along with tracker files, git repository and some others.
It is not recommended to copy the database but if you want to do it. If you still want to do it I would suggest to use phpmyadim, adminer or even pure mysql to dump the DB and import on the test server. Be careful, the database structure changed, and many things might break.

**Safe way:**

Copy the *whole* 6.6 server and *then* upgrade Tuleap using [this script](https://tuleap.net/wiki/index.php?pagename=Installation%20%26%20Administration%2FHow%20to%20install&group_id=101#Upgrade_to_a_newer_version_of_Tuleap)